Fixed panel which emulates an OpenFileDialog
I'm pretty sure that it's a newbie question but I can't find the answer.  I'm looking for a component for a VB Windows Form which displays all the information of an OpenFileDialog panel.  The problem with the OpenFileDialog is that it's a distinct dialog whereas I need a file navigation bar which is instead integrated within the displayed form.  Basically, I'm looking to embed the panel of the OpenFileDialog on my form.  Does any such component exist?  Thanks!
